# Error 1046 in AS3. 3 simple buttons, nothing works?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I'm trying to make a simple start up screen for a game i'm making, and I put a button (Backbtn)on Frame 2, to go back to frame 1, but nothing works, it just flies through the frames, the Stop(); doesn't work, and I keep getting error 1046: Type was not found or was not a compile-time constant: Backbtn.

Any help, this is my code!

```
 import flash.events.MouseEvent;

 stop();

HTP.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, goClick);
PlayButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, goPlay);
Backbtn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, goBack);

function goClick(event:MouseEvent): void 
{
trace("two");
    gotoAndStop(2);
}

function goPlay(event:MouseEvent): void
{
    trace("three");
gotoAndStop(3);
}

function goBack(event:MouseEvent) : void
{
trace("TEST");
gotoAndStop(1);
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: This looks like AS2 to me. Are you sure it's AS3?

Comment: Also, have you named the button `Backbtn` correctly? AS is case-sensitive.

Comment: Slightly unrelated, but AS2/AS3 object identifiers conventionally begin with a lower case letter, to differentiate them from class names which begin with an upper case letter

Comment: Pranav, it worked fine in AS3 until I added Backbtn, HTP & PlayButton worked fine, took me to the frames they wanted. Not sure if this is anything to do with the fact Backbtn is on frame 2, will that affect anything? Pretty new to this! And yes I have checked, it's spelt exactly the same everywhere, the instance, the button name and in the code.

Thanks for the reply! :)

Comment: @PranavHosangadi It looks like AS3, and it's called Camel Casing

Comment: Of course! put `Backbtn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, goBack);` and `function goBack(event:MouseEvent) : void.....` in the second frame, it should work

Comment: Done that, as both of you said, but still getting error 1046? Should I delete the button, reimport it and try again completely, keeping the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### What's wrong with my code?

**BackBtn** isn't defined until frame 2, therefore it is **undefined** until frame 2.

### Oh noes!  How do I fix this?

Change your code to:

```
 import flash.events.MouseEvent;

 stop();

HTP.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, goClick);
PlayButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, goPlay);

function goClick(event:MouseEvent): void 
{
trace("two");
    gotoAndStop(2);
}

function goPlay(event:MouseEvent): void
{
    trace("three");
gotoAndStop(3);
}
```

And put this code on frame 2:

```
Backbtn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, goBack);
function goBack(event:MouseEvent) : void
{
    trace("TEST");
    gotoAndStop(1);
}
```

Comment: Still giving me error 1046! Type was not found or isn't a compile-time constant. Thanks anyway for trying! Have no idea, tried re-inserting the entire button/ instance, still nope.

Comment: @user3185840 On frame 2, put `trace(Backbtn)` and tell me what it says in the output

Comment: I'm getting no trace, no code is working at all, not even stop(); it's still just playing the whole thing on a loop! Ahhh what is happening!?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know what you mean! What's Air?

Comment: @user3185840 Nevermind, will it be okay for you to email me the .fla?  I need to look into this further

Comment: I'm in Flash, if that's what you mean! :)

Comment: @user3185840 Can you email me the fla?

Comment: Yeah, of course, i'll email it to the address on your account! Thank you!

Comment: @user3185840 I've emailed you the fix